# What does it mean to differentiate $f(\theta_1)/f(\theta_2) = C$ with respect to theta?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics

In the book I am reading, at one point they differentiate Snell's Law with respect to ${\theta}$:
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\Bigl(\frac{\sin(\theta_{1})}{\sin(\theta_{2})}=\frac{\eta_{2}}{\eta_{1}}\Bigr),$$
which they claim gives the result:
$$\frac{\cos(\theta_{1})d\theta_{1}}{\cos(\theta_{2})d\theta_{2}}=\frac{\eta_{2}}{\eta_{1}}.$$

I have no reason not to believe that this is true, but I really don't understand what it means to differentiate two different variables ($\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$) with respect to a third variable ($\theta$). I suppose the two variables aren't necessarily completely independent as they are both values on the axis of $\theta$, but I can't really grasp it. $\frac{\eta_{2}}{\eta_{1}}$ is also a constant, so why would it not go to $0$?

Here is a link to the section of the book in question:
http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Reflection_Models/Specular_Reflection_and_Transmission.html#eq:spherical-L-transmitted

and their definition of Snell's Law:
http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Reflection_Models/Specular_Reflection_and_Transmission.html#eq:snells-law

I am new here, so apologies in advance if I have done something incorrectly in this post. Any nudge in the right direction would be really appreciated!

EDIT: Actually, $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are just functions of $\theta$ aren't they? Oops. So I guess I need to think of it like this:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\Bigl(\frac{f(g(\theta))}{f(h(\theta))}=C\Bigr),$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two functions of $\theta$:

1. $\frac{f(g(\theta))}{f(h(\theta))}$, and
2. $C$ (which is constant as a function of theta).

The derivative of the second one is zero, of course. The derivative of the first can be computed using the chain rule and quotient rule. It's a little simpler to rewrite as
$$
f(g(\theta)) = C f(h(\theta))
$$
We can then differentiate both sides, using the chain rule, to  get
$$
f'(g(\theta)) g'(\theta) = C f'(h(\theta)) h'(\theta)
$$
Dividing through a bit, that gives
$$
\frac{f'(g(\theta))}{f'(h(\theta))} \frac{g'(\theta)}{h'(\theta)} = C.
$$
Replacing $f$ by $\sin$, and$g$ and $h$ respectively by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, that becomes
$$
\frac{\cos(\theta_1(\theta))}{\cos(\theta_2(\theta))} \frac{\theta_1'(\theta)}{\theta_2'(\theta)} = C.
$$
And then switching to Leibniz notation, and omitting the "theta" argument, we have
$$
\frac{\cos(\theta_1(\theta))}{\cos(\theta_2(\theta))} \frac{\frac{d\theta_1}{d\theta}}{\frac{d\theta_2}{d\theta}} = C.
$$
And finally, "cancelling" the $d\theta$s (a la the chain rule), this becomes
$$
\frac{\cos(\theta_1(\theta))}{\cos(\theta_2(\theta))} \frac{d\theta_1}{d\theta_2} = C.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much this makes complete sense now!! I had confused myself, at first by thinking of $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ as variables instead of functions, and then by trying to differentiate the two together and = $0$ rather than separating them onto the left and right hand side and differentiating separately, which makes so much more sense.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: By the way, what you did was exactly the right thing, esp. your realization that they were both functions of a single (unmentioned) variable $\theta$. This is yet another example of (i) why the Leibniz notation can be baffling, combined with (ii) how the Leibniz notation can be powerful. Notice that in my last formula, if you replace $\theta_1(\theta)$ with $\theta_1$, etc., the "hidden" variable $\theta$ completely disappears .. it's no wonder people have a hard time dealing with stuff like this!